# Mongo array filters doesn't work as expected in NodeJS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to perform an update on my database using the following query:

```
itemCollection.update(
    {
    'questions.optional':{$exists:true}
    },
    {
        $set:{"questions.optional.$[].items.$[itemField].name":"עכשיו"}
    },
    {
        arrayFilters:
        [
            {"itemField.id": itemId}
        ],
        $multi:true
    }, (error) => {
        if(!error){
            menuUpdate.redisClientDel(item, next, err);
        }
    }
)
```

However I get this error:

```
No array filter found for identifier 'itemField' in path 'questions.optional.$[].items.$[itemField].name'
```

I tested the query with Studio 3T before applying it in my code, and it worked. What can be the reason for it not to work when I use it with NodeJS?

Comment: What version of mongo are you using?

Comment: Mongo version is 4.2.0.
I noticed that the Mongo driver version for Node is 2.0.55, so I guess that's the problem.

Comment: I'm just thinking that if it works in studio 3t then maybe the version in node is the problem.

Comment: If that is not the problem, then it would be better to show us your collection. But first try to update driver version to 3.*